# Элита собирается в общество, - такое возможно?

Tags: выбор-слов

> К двум часам здесь, на комплексные обеды по 16 евро, собирается в
>   общество очень взрослая интеллектуальная элита. Незаурядное местечко.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Можно сразу сказать, что "общество" здесь лишнее, как Мария, но у меня нет в этом уверенности, и, если действительно можно найти аргументы в пользу этого варианта, было бы любопытно. Звучит красочнее, пикантнее так, что ли.

Comment: А запятая в заголовке случайно стоит или нет?

Comment: Зап/тире - мой любимый знак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение слова **общество** по [**Ефремовой**](http://tolkslovar.ru/o2444.html):
1. Совокупность людей, объединенных исторически обусловленными социальными формами совместной жизни и деятельности.
2. Круг людей, объединенных общностью положения, происхождения, интересов.
3. Добровольное, постоянно действующее объединение людей для какой-л. цели. // Организация, союз людей, ставящих себе общие задачи. // Промышленное или торговое товарищество, объединяющее предпринимателей.
4. Круг людей, с которыми кто-л. находится в тесном общении; среда.
5. Несколько человек, проводящих вместе время; компания.

Термин "элита" ведет свое происхождение от латинского *eligere* — выбирать; в современной литературе получил широкое хождение от французского *elite* — лучший, отборный, избранный.

В нашем случае получается: "особенные люди собираются в компанию (или компанией) к двум часам". Это — проза.
Если же автору очень хочется подчеркнуть *незаурядность* происходящего, тогда есть смысл использовать *незаурядное* (на грани плеоназма) выражение: "элита собирается в общество". Это — с пиететом.

Answer (score 1):

просто "собирается интеллектуальная элита", без "общества"

Comment: По смыслу она кучкуется, и именно к двум часам. Но предложим вариант авторую

Comment: Собирается — это и есть намек на кучкование, в отличие, например,  от "приходит", "сходится".

Comment: Спасибо, М_Г, будем думать!